# What's the word for something that determines what choice to make?

Tags: single-word-requests

Say there are multiple factors that influences decision making, and one factor can solely determine which choice to make.

Is there a word for this kind of key factor?

Comment: Perhaps, the "deciding" factor.

Comment: @vanderpn Suggest you post that as an answer. It's a good one. But I might feel inclined to hyphenate it myself - though others may disagree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've commonly heard the phrase "the **deciding factor**."

Merriam-Webster defines [deciding factor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deciding%20factor) as:

> something that causes someone to make a particular decision

I believe that the fact that this phrase has its own dictionary entry evidences its popularity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **pivotal** factor.

**Pivotal** - [**M-W**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivotal)

> of crucial importance in relation to the development or success of something else.

Eg:  A decision that was pivotal to our success. - [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pivotal)

Also, [**Decisive factor**](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/decisive%20factor) means,

> a point or a fact or remark that settles something conclusively.